# Join multiple files into single file

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, userscripts

I'm trying to come up with a way to have multiple files joined into one prior debugging/publishing without adding extra "garbage" into the final code.

My first instinct was to create "placeholders", then replace them with content of other files.

For instance, I'd have `main.user.js`, `another.js`, `mycss.css` and `changes.txt` files.
In `main.user.js` I'd have something like:

```
(function(css, changes) {

  console.log(css);
  console.log(changes);

  //@@another.js@@

})(`//@@mycss.com@@`, `//@@changes.txt@@`);
```

This would require some kind of script that would search and replace strings in a file prior running debugger or publishing the script...

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

*My vscode/node.js knowledge is very limited, just know how to setup a basic workspace and create debug launcher*

Comment: sounds to me like you want a JS bundler

Answer (score 1):

You can use "npm fs" && "npm path".

```
npm install fs path
```

Make one file and use this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const placeholders = {
  'css': 'mycss.css',
  'changes': 'changes.txt',
  'another': 'another.js',
};

const mainFile = 'main.user.js';
const outputFile = 'output.js';

// Read the main user script
let outputContent = fs.readFileSync(mainFile, 'utf-8');

// Replace placeholders with file contents
for (const placeholder in placeholders) {
  const filePath = placeholders[placeholder];
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
  const placeholderPattern = `//@@${placeholder}@@`;
  outputContent = outputContent.replace(placeholderPattern, fileContent);
}

// Write the combined content to the output file
fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, outputContent);

console.log(`Join completed ${outputFile}`);
```

Then run this. it will be save as output as you want

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! This also opened up possibility to change other parts of the script, for example version, so no I can use CalVer instead of SemVer.